# How to make <div> inside a <form> element as required

Tags: html, ionic-framework

I want to make this div containing `.action-bar` as required so that I can validate my form.

```html
<form name="forms.subsections[0].formName">
  <div class="item item-divider">
    Photo
  </div>

  <div class="item item-stacked-label">
 <span class="input-label">Store Photo</span>
  <div class="container">
    <img ng-src="">
  </div>
  <div class="action-bar" ng-click="takePhoto()" >
   <i class='icon ion-ios-camera-outline'></i>
  Take Picture
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: i tried finding out how to attach required attribute to divs ..but did not get any proper direction